# Как заставить метод понимать тип дочернего класса

Tags: c#, ооп, шаблоны-проектирования

Пытаюсь реализовать шаблон ООП "Фабрика". Т.е. есть несколько объектов и провайдеров, каждый из которых работает с определенным типом объекта. Но я не могу понять, правильно ли я сделал, потому что получается, что каждый провайдер в своем абстрактном методе использует всё равно родителя объекта и приходится каждый раз приводить руками его к нужному типу.

Прошу, подскажите, можно ли в провайдере сразу реализовать метода, который был бы от абстрактного, но понимал, с каким конкретно объектом он должен работать?

Или есть другой подходящий шаблон?

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public abstract class Employee
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
    }

    public class Boss : Employee
    {
        public bool IsTopManager { get; set; } = true;
    }

    public class Developer : Employee
    {
        public bool IsSenior { get; set; }
    }

    public abstract class EmployeeProvider
    {
        public abstract void Hire(Employee employee);
        public abstract void Dismiss(Employee employee);
    }

    public class DeveloperProvider : EmployeeProvider
    {
        public override void Dismiss(Employee employee)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        public override void Hire(Employee employee)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }

    public class BossProvider : EmployeeProvider
    {
        public override void Dismiss(Employee employee)
        {
            DismissBoss(employee as Boss); // Можно ли избавиться от "as Boss"?
        }           
            
        public override void Hire(Employee employee)
        {
            **HireBoss(employee as Boss);** // Можно ли избавиться от "as Boss"?
        }

        private void DismissBoss(Boss boss)
        {
            if (boss.IsTopManager)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Top manager is dismissed");
            }
        }

        private void HireBoss(Boss boss)
        {
            if (boss.IsTopManager)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Top manager is hired");
            }
        }


        // Хочется, чтобы в итоге было так:
        /*public override void Hire(Boss boss)
        {
            if (boss.IsTopManager)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Top manager is hired");
            }
        }*/         

    }

    public static void Main()
    {
        EmployeeProvider employeeProvider = new BossProvider(); // Тут может быть любой провайдер

        Boss boss = new Boss();
        employeeProvider.Hire(boss);
        employeeProvider.Dismiss(boss);
    }
}
```

Comment: А если реально просто сделать код как в "Хочется, чтобы в итоге было так", то так не работает, ругается?

Comment: на основе чего ты делал свою иерархию классов? Почему ты думаешь, что сейчас у тебя тут присутствует какая-нибудь Фабрика?

Comment: @CrazyElf Не работает, потому что объявление абстрактного метода отличается от реализованного. Я тоже думал, что на наследуемые объекты он не будет ругаться

Comment: Сделайте вот так `public abstract class EmployeeProvider<T> where T : Employee { public abstract void Hire(T employee); public abstract void Dismiss(T employee); }` и вот так `public class BossProvider : EmployeeProvider<Boss>`. Тогда можно будет вот так `public override void Dismiss(Boss boss)`.

Comment: @Grundy тут примерно описано https://metanit.com/sharp/patterns/2.1.php

Comment: @Игорь код в твоем вопросе не связан с кодом по ссылке, кроме суффикса `Provider` у некоторых классов.

Comment: Но как правильно подметил @Grundy, это не похоже на фабрику. Фабрика делает экземпляры, а не модифицирует их.

Comment: @aepot То, что вы предложили очень помогло. 
Единственно, правильно ли я понимаю, что теперь нельзя будет сделать какой-то общий экземпляр провайдера и вызывать методы?
  BossProvider bosseProvider = new BossProvider(); 
  DeveloperProvider developerProvider = new DeveloperProvider();

  EmployeeProvider provider = bosseProvider; // Ошибка

  Boss boss = new Boss();
  provider.Hire(boss);
  provider.Dismiss(boss);

Comment: Ну да, есть такое. Но это плата за обобщение. Можно еще абстракцию накинуть типа `interface IEmployeeProvider` без обобщения, и от нее унаследоваться в абстрактном классе, но в ней будет пусто. Так, чисто чтобы была возможность красиво запихивать эти провайдеры в коллекции. Но надо ли оно вам. Подумайте еще над архитектурой объектной модели, вы пока решаете последствия, а не изначальную проблему.

Comment: @aepot спасибо за помощь.